# SSIS job fails via automation

Tags: ssis, etl

I've developed an SSIS job in Visual Studio 2017, targeting Microsoft SQL server 2016.  When I execute it manually via Visual Studio it runs to completion with no errors.  The original deployment to the SQL server was running just fine via the "run at 11pm" schedule that was setup.

Now I've made some change and re-published, and it's failing to run.  I've tried to wrap the entire section of code in try/catch/finally blocks and have the catch send me an email, for example, but I don't get anything.

What can I do to debug why this fails to run via the schedule but doesn't fail to run from Visual Studio?  The job runs as me on the SQL server so it's not a user permission error, to the best of my knowledge.

I can't directly log into the SQL server, but I can have IT run some things for me or export a share if there's a better log I can find.

Comment: You say, you've "tried to wrap the entire section of code in try/catch/finally blocks", but this can only apply to scripts. How do you know that the problem isn't being caused by another component? Have you tried configuring the Package OnError eventhandler to send an email?

Comment: It's the Script Task piece that is failing.  I can tell that just by the "flow" of what updates and what doesn't in the DB.  I'll go google the OnError handler now, thanks.

Comment: What changes have you made to the package that made it stop working? Have you added Connection Managers to the project for example?

Comment: @DeanOC The OnError event handler worked great, thanks.  If you want to post that as an answer I'll check it as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I generally configure the Package OnError eventhandler to send an email with the exception details.

If the problem is in a script, you can use the try..catch block to raise an event in the `catch` block and provide a useful message for your email. e.g.

```
catch (Exception e)
{
     Dts.Events.FireError(0, null, string.Format("Error parsing file: {0}", e),null, 0);
      Dts.TaskResult = (int)DTSExecResult.Failure;
}
```